# How to use useFormState with JWT Authentication in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, forms, authentication, next.js, react-hooks

My goal is to retrieve the token on the backend to relate the item created by form submission with  id of the user who has submitted the form.

My code:

src\app\offers\create\page.tsx:

```
"use client"
const [state, formAction] = useFormState(createOffer, {
  fieldValues: initialFormValue,
});
```

src\app\actions.ts:

```
"use server"
export async function createOffer(prevState: FormState, formData: FormData) {
 // ...
}
```

Perhaps it's possible to pass the token in `initialState` (second argument of `useFormState`).
Or maybe it's possible to attach the token on every front-end request (like HttpInterceptor-s in Angular do) and somehow retrieve the token in the backend middleware?